# How to handle in error in async/await in vue typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, async-await

The code snippet is

```
    async getInfo(): Promise<any>{
    let response;
    try{
        response = await Axios.get('api/***')
        //response.json()  
                        //what is json here?
                        //Error here is "[ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<any>'."      
    }catch(err){
        response = err;
        console.log(err)
    }
    return response;
}
```

and in here the **err** doesnot print as a json, how can i convert it to json? it shows like this
`Error: Request failed with status code 403`

Comment: You don't need to do `response.json()`, response itself should be a json object. Check by console.log(response)

Comment: @Helpinghand his problem is not the response printing but rather err object printing as json

Comment: yeah that correct @Helpinghand, its a JSON only and why this err is not a JSON? any thing which i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Sam err is a instance of AxiosError, the object have a property called `response`. Then, you can transform `err` to your json object: `response = err.response || {error: err.error};`

Comment: Just got to see this https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960 and solved my problem and thats what you replied, Thanks.